# how to run this (matplotlib) in sublime text and cloud9 (c9.io)

Tags: python, sublimetext3, cloud9-ide

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

In cloud9 I don't get what port 8080 means.

Comment: Port 8080 is sometimes used for HTTP servers. I don't know anything about cloud9, but if you're connecting to it via a URL, does appending `:8080` do anything?

Comment: It shows this "Important: use os.getenv(PORT, 8080) as the port and os.getenv(IP, 0.0.0.0) as the host in your scripts!"

Comment: Port 8080 is the default port where Cloud9 applications should be served. When you serve your application on 8080 then you can preview it with the application preview link provided. You should also take a look at https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application for more info.